# KnpSnappy and CKditor : how to allow bold tags to my pdf?

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, knp-snappy

I'm working in Symfony with Ckeditor to write some content, and I use KnpSnappy to convert them as a PDF file.
My issue is when I use tags like bold or italic to my text, I can't see it to my pdf.
There is an option to allows tag to KnpSnappy ?

Update : solved, It was because of the option striptags, I removed it and it fixed my issue :

```
<p>{{ annonce.contactAdresse|striptags|replace({'&nbsp;':''})|raw }}</p>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with ckeditor and phpoffice/phpword, the majority of ckeditor's styles don't work

Comment: I solved it, check in your pdf template, if you have "striptags" option and remove it  : 
<p>{{ annonce.contactAdresse|striptags|replace({'&nbsp;':''})|raw }}</p>